# Hyperlink the cell in another sheet where there is a match found

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a cell in `sheet1` in excel and the same name in `sheet2` in the same sheet in a fixed column.

I am trying to find the text of `sheet1` in `sheet2` and hyperlink the cell reference to the text in `sheet1`

I tried doing this

```
=HYPERLINK("#sheet2!"&CELL("address",INDEX(sheet2!C:C,MATCH("Stack Overflow",sheet2!C:C,0))), "Stack Overflow")
```

But getting "Reference isn't valid"

The formula suggested in comments works when `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` are used as the names of the sheets, but gives error when the names of sheets are different -

The product info sheet screenshot -
[image]

The sheet1 sheet screenshot-
[image]

Formula used -

```
=HYPERLINK(CELL("address",INDEX('Product Info'!C:C,MATCH("Stack Overflow",'Product Info'!C:C,0))),"Stack Overflow")
```

Error
[image]

Comment: `=HYPERLINK(CELL("address",INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH("Stack Overflow",Sheet2!C:C,0))), "Stack Overflow")`

Comment: I am getting the error with parentheses, shows in red

Comment: Strange, works for me.

Comment: I am sorry works or me too, I had copied it partially

Comment: @JvdVI am getting error  of "The address of this site is not valid. Check the address and try again" when I have a name of the sheet2 as some other name - ``` =HYPERLINK(CELL("address",INDEX('Product Info'!C:C,MATCH("Stack",'Product Info'!C:C,0))), "Stack")```

Comment: Updated my question with the screenshot, formula used - ```=HYPERLINK(CELL("address",INDEX('Product Info'!C:C,MATCH("Stack",'Product Info'!C:C,0))), "Stack")```

Comment: I can't help but to report that `=HYPERLINK(CELL("address",INDEX('Product Info'!C:C,MATCH("Stack Overflow",'Product Info'!C:C,0))),"Stack Overflow")` works for me. Are you sure the value is actually present?

Comment: @JvdV I updated my question with all 3 screenshots of sheet1, Product Info sheet and the error

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this, sorry. Hopefully someone else comes up with ideas.

Comment: I have got the problem here but dont know how to resolve, when I renamed the sheet ```Product Info` to just ```Product```, it works, seems that there should not be two words separated by space in the sheet name. The problem is I cannot change the sheet names